# Dynamic drop down base on previous selection

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, postgresql

I am using postgres database.. and my both the drop down must extract values from database..
Using the 1st selected value...the optins in second drop down must change.. nut the option must cum from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try type your title into google?

```
http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html
```